# How to increment html input name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

how can i increment an array inside a html name="" that is put inside a jQuery .after()?

**Like this**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_products').click(function() {
      $('.products_tr:last').after('<tr class="products_tr"><td><input id="quantity" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="invoice[products_attributes][1][quantity]"></td></tr>');
    });
  });
```

It's supposed to add extra rows to a invoice, and its working but in order to save it correctly to the database the '[1]' inside `name="invoice[products_attributes][1][quantity]` needs to increment. And it needs to increment based on the last value.

That code is dynamically created by Ruby On Rails btw.

Anybody know a way to accomplish this? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: `'...name="invoice[products_attributes]['+ a value+'...'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the total rows(as index start from 0 so no need to add 1) to it so that you will get new index for the newly generated row and use `class="quantity"` as `id` must be unique,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#add_products').click(function() {
      l=$('.products_tr').length;// to get total
      $('.products_tr:last').after('<tr class="products_tr"><td><input '+
          ' class="quantity" class="form-control" type="text" value="" '+
          ' name="invoice[products_attributes]['+l+'][quantity]"></td></tr>');
   });
 });
```

As @Pete has commented, and if you have a delete button then use a global variable and increment it like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var counter = $('.products_tr').length; // initially it is equal to length of all rows, let it start from 0
   $('#add_products').click(function() {
      $('.products_tr:last').after('<tr class="products_tr"><td><input '+
          ' class="quantity" class="form-control" type="text" value="" '+
          ' name="invoice[products_attributes]['+counter+'][quantity]"></td></tr>');
      counter++;
   });
 });
```

Comment: The only problem would be if there is a remove row button too

Comment: Actually after trying again it doesn't work because it doesn't go past [1]. when i add a third row it stays on [1].

Comment: Oh yes my mistake sorry i messed up the the counter++;